# Apache 2.4 / Windows / Multi-IP based VHosts for SSL/Non-SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I'm setting up my Apache server so that it has 2 internal IP addresses for the NIC.  One will be bound to all port 80 traffic, and the other to port 443 traffic.  The reason I'm doing this is that when I browse to one of my sites that is not SSL enabled, Apache tries to serve up the first certificate it finds in the VHosts file, even though it doesn't belong to the site I'm requesting.  This causes an SSL warning because it does not match the domain.

From what I understand, the best way to fix this problem is to set up the NIC so that it has 2 IP addresses.  Here is what I have so far.

**NIC Card Setup Static IPs:**

> 10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.4.
>   Both on same Subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.

I want to set up my Apache so that 10.0.0.2 will handle port 80 traffic, and any requests for HTTPS for all sites defined for that IP will fail.  All HTTPS traffic will go through 10.0.0.4.

I have the following in my **httpd.conf** file

```
Listen 10.0.0.2:80   Listen 10.0.0.4:443

NameVirtualHost 10.0.0.2:80   NameVirtualHost 10.0.0.4:443
```

In my vhosts.conf file, I have my sites set up like this.

## HTTP VIRTUAL HOSTS

ServerName domainwhatever.com
     ...site declaration stuff here...

```
# HTTPS VIRTUAL HOSTS

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.4:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:\sites\site1.com"
    ServerName site1.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "c:\ssl\site1.com\CERTFILE.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:\ssl\site1.com\CERTFILE.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile "c:\ssl\site1.com\BUNDLEFILE.crt" </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.4:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:\sites\site2.com"
    ServerName site2.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "c:\ssl\site2.com\CERTFILE.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:\ssl\site2.com\CERTFILE.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile "c:\ssl\site2.com\BUNDLEFILE.crt" </VirtualHost>
```

I have quite a bit of HTTP (10.0.0.2:80) VHost entries, but only show one in this example.  Right now I have two sites that are HTTPS and need to use the 10.0.0.4 IP, but want to be able to add more in the future.

I can't browse the https sites.  Chrome does not connect.  Any idea where I'm going wrong here???

Comment: What is the actual error message you are getting?

Comment: your "VirtualHost" directive contains 10.0.0.0 instead of 10.0.0.4 so the VirtualHosts don't match.

Comment: @JennyD - not getting an error message, but when I try to browse to one of my SSL sites it doesn't connect.  Just tries and tries and fails to connect.

Comment: @AndreasRogge - that was a copy/paste mistake.  In my real vhost they are correct and I've updated my example to fix too.